# TSerializer serializer = new TSerializer() in C#

Tags: java, c#, serialization, thrift

Is there any equivalent of `TSerializer` in the Thrift C# API.

I am trying to use thrift serialization and then push the serialized object into MQ, not using Thrift transport mechanism. On the other end I'll deserialize it to the actual message.

I can do it in Java but not in C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Apache Thrift C# library doesn't have a TSerializer presently. However it does have a TMemoryBuffer (essentially a transport that reads/writes memory) which works perfectly for this kind of thing. Create a TMemoryBuffer, construct a protocol (like TBinaryProtocol) and then serialize your messages and send them as blobs from the TMemoryBuffer.

For example:

```
  TMemoryBuffer trans = new TMemoryBuffer();     //Transport
  TProtocol proto = new TCompactProtocol(trans); //Protocol
  PNWF.Trade trade = new PNWF.Trade(initStuff);  //Message type (thrift struct)

  trade.Write(proto);                    //Serialize the message to memory

  byte[] bytes = trans.GetBuffer();      //Get the serialized message bytes
  //SendAMQPMsg(bytes);                  //Send them!
```

To receive the message you just do the reverse. TMemoryBuffer has a constructor you can use to set the received bytes to read from.

```
 public TMemoryBuffer(byte[] buf);
```

Then you just call your struct Read() method on the read side I/O stack.

This isn't much more code (maybe less) than using the Java TSerializer helper and it is a bit more universal across Apache Thrift language libraries. You may find TMemoryBuffer is the way to go everywhere!

Answer (score 3):

Credit due to the other answer on this page, and from here:

http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2008/08/29/c-thrift-examples/

Rather than expecting everyone to take the explanations and write their own functions, here are two functions to serialize and deserialize generalized thrift objects in C#:

```
public static byte[] serialize(TBase obj)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    TProtocol tProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(new TStreamTransport(stream, stream));
    obj.Write(tProtocol);
    return stream.ToArray();
}

public static T deserialize<T>(byte[] data) where T : TBase, new()
{
    T result = new T();
    var buffer = new TMemoryBuffer(data);
    TProtocol tProtocol = new TBinaryProtocol(buffer);
    result.Read(tProtocol);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an RPC framework that uses the standard thrift Protocol named "thrifty", and it is the same effect as using thrift IDL to define the service, that is, thrify can be compatible with code that uses thrift IDL, and it include serializer：

```
[ThriftStruct]
public class LogEntry
{

    [ThriftConstructor]
    public LogEntry([ThriftField(1)]String category, [ThriftField(2)]String message)
    {
        this.Category = category;
        this.Message = message;
    }

    [ThriftField(1)]
    public String Category { get; }

    [ThriftField(2)]
    public String Message { get; }
}

ThriftSerializer s = new ThriftSerializer(ThriftSerializer.SerializeProtocol.Binary);
byte[] s = s.Serialize<LogEntry>();

s.Deserialize<LogEntry>(s);
```

more detail: https://github.com/endink/Thrifty